# How do I kill a (summoned with commands) named Ender Dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

This is probably a stupid question, but here goes:

I was trying out some new ideas for a hub I'm building on a server. I summoned a named Ender Dragon and now I can't kill it with any sword (it doesn't seem to have a hitbox) or other physical means so I want to remove it with commands.

The command I used to summon it was `/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1,CustomName:"Welcome to the Hub!",Silent:1}` and despite all efforts with the /killall command I can't get rid of it...

The server is running Spigot 1.8.4 with Essentials, EssentialsSpawn, PermissionsEX, WorldEdit and Multiverse (Core, SignPortals and NetherPortals). Essentials and PEX are the correct versions made by the Spigot team to work on 1.8.*.

The world this is on is a Superflat normal world (`/mvcreate Hub normal -t superflat` if that helps).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teleport or fly over to it, then:

```
/kill @e[type=EnderDragon,c=1,r=2]
```

Comment: It simply gives me the "player not found" error message...

Comment: @Zlambe Odd, the command works for me with an EnderDragon made with the summon command you gave. I don't think "player not found" is even an error message that it should give, it says "The entity UUID is provided is in an invalid format" if you're not close enough to the dragon. Try doing `/say @e[type=EnderDragon]`, does the EnderDragon you're trying to get rid of show on the list?

Comment: It says: [Zlambe] Welcome to the Hub! and Welcome the the Hub

Comment: @Zlambe Since those are the only two EnderDragons (loaded), you could perhaps try `/kill @e[type=EnderDragon]` (and replace the second one if you want it).

Comment: Still just gives player not found...

Comment: @Zlambe That's very odd. So `/say` can detect it, but `/kill` doesn't? Try some other commands like `/entitydata @e[type=EnderDragon] {}` or `/testfor @e[type=EnderDragon]`. You may need to use an external tool to get rid of the EnderDragon.

Comment: Okay I'll try it. Thanks for the help. I don't know if this makes a difference but I just realised that I put a test Dragon in one world and the real one above the hub (a separate world) so would that perhaps be why? Sorry for the bother.

Comment: In the end I just restored to a backup. This answer was still useful though, so thanks @colorfusion

Comment: @Zlambe you are using Essentials which overwrites the `/kill` command either change it back in the configuration or do `/minecraft:kill` to explicitly call Minecraft's `kill` command.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/kill @e[type=ender_dragon,limit=1,distance=..2]`. You might want to add `sort=nearest` too, because `@e` is no longer sorted by default

Answer (score 1):

If it's a hostile mob, setting the gamemode to peaceful should do the trick.

Comment: Ender dragons don't despawn on peaceful difficulty

Answer (score -1):

try using the command /kill @e in a command blcok and then power it i kills every mob but you respawn to get a command block use the /give command

Answer (score -1):

Really simple. Command `/butcher` it needs WorldEdit

Comment: Maybe you should add some details on how the command works? I doubt typing butcher would just kill an ender dragon without targeting it or providing additional parameters

Answer (score -1):

In MC 1.11.2 try:

```
/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]
```

This got rid of the ender dragon my son spawned on our server.